# Find probability function, find constant a

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, constants

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{x^2} & |x| > a\\
0 & |x|\leqslant a
\end{cases}$$
How to find a ? 
I tried to integrate on intervals $(-a,0)$, $(0,a)$, but it equals $0$.

Comment: Try integrating over $(-\infty,\infty)$. To do so, break that up in the intervals $(-\infty,-a]$, $(-a,a)$ and $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: Shouldn't $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{x^2} & x > a\\
0 & x\leqslant a
\end{cases} $$ or $$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{2}{x^2} & |x| > a\\
0 & |x| \leqslant a
\end{cases} $$?

Comment: @stud_iisc thank you. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $1= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-a} \frac{2}{x^2} dx + \int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2} dx = 2*\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2} dx = \frac{4}{a}.$